# How long can I stay with ASP.Net 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

In 2005 I wrote a simple ASP.NET 2.0 website for a corporate client, and I host it on a rented business-grade server in a datacenter.

It doesn't do anything fancy at all. It connects to  SQL Server 2005 and uses one Web Service that adds data to the same database.

It has run without a single downtime for 7 years now, and I'd like to keep it that way.

Now the datacenter is talking about upgrading the server to ASP.NET 4.5.

Is this likely to break anything basic, like CRUD transactions?

How long can I safely stay with Net 2.0? Years more?

Ii don't need any new features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mainstream support](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=pn&alpha=.net%20framework) for .NET 2.0 ended in 2011, extended support ends in 2016. SQL Server 2005 has the same timeframe, ending in 2016.

If your hosting provider is moving to .NET 4.5 then you have the option of staying with that provider or upgrading your application.

If you don't have anything special going on in your application have you tried to just upgrade the application code to .NET 4.5? If you have not used anything that was depcreciated (and I don't know if .NET does that or not like SQL Server) with 4.5 it should be a smooth upgrade for you. IMO.